# Cakephp updating from 2.4 tot 2.5: Fatal error

Tags: cakephp, updating

I've have multiple cakephp sites so my core files are in different lib place.
No I'm updating from 2.4.5 to 2.5.8 by changing the CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH.

This time I'm getting a fatal error:
Unsupported operand types in /home/*/cake_lib/cakephp-2.5.8/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php on line 126

I don't find where to problem is.

Comment: What does your error log say? What happens when you turn on debug mode for your app? Do you get a stack trace of any kind? More info is needed to pinpoint your problem.

Comment: Debug mode is set on 2. And the fatal error mentioned is the only error log. But I tried something and I think I need to update a plugin. I think it's not compatible with the 2.5 version.